# UTF8 Characters not displayed correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding, utf-8

In my mysql database i have string with german umlauts (ä, ö, ü).

I query them with php/mysql and when displayed on my website, they show up like this:

�

I have this html in my website:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

edit: i have changed all collations to utf8_unicode_ci but the problem still persists

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: How are they encoded in the database? How are you fetching them? How are you building the page?

Comment: @Wooble 1. i dont know, 2. mysql_query("SELECT ...") , 3. handwritten with notepad++

Comment: Step 1: figure out what encoding you're using *everywhere*.

Comment: How did the data get into the database? How do you not know what encoding it's in? You can't just throw random bytes onto a page and claim it's utf-8.

Comment: is it the collation that specifies the encoding in mysql? if so, it is latin1.

Comment: @Wooble 1. submitted via a POST-webform and then inserted with sql INSERT. 2. i dont know cause i didnt know where to look for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have written html meta tag as charset=UTF-8 and you have set Collation as utf8_unicode_ci character set and its not working then you must use

```
 mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

use this where you have made your connection file, like this:-

```
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = mysql_select_db('testing');
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```